# Can I install pixiewps in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, hacking

Can I install pixiewps in Ubuntu? If yes, then can you please guide me through the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pixiewps is a tool written in C used to bruteforce offline the WPS pin
> exploiting the low or non-existing entropy of some APs (pixie dust
> attack).

This means it should work in all Linux distros including Ubuntu.

#### How to install it?

Download [pixiewps-master.zip](https://codeload.github.com/wiire/pixiewps/zip/master).

Pixiewps requires libssl. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Pixiewps can be built and installed by running:

```
~/pixiewps$ make
~/pixiewps$ sudo make install
```

Quoted from : https://github.com/wiire/pixiewps

Answer (score 3):

Via PPA, for 14.04:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cybersec/chaos-ppa-v1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pixiewps
```